# TypeError in controller#edit can't cast PG::Result to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in helper like

```
 def m_product_ids(ids)
    product = MProduct.where(product_id: ids).select(:product_id,:product_name,:product_order)
    product.map { |r| ["#{r[:product_id]}:#{r[:product_name]}#{r[:product_order]}", "#{r[:product_id]}"] }
 end
```

when I call `m_product_ids` with `options_for` select in edit form its raising the error like

> can't cast PG::Result to string.

Comment: Is `MProduct` you model or something else?

Comment: My only thought but I don't know if this is true or not is that the function is not returning product.map but product. So perhaps try setting product equal to product.map and then return product instead? My only guess. I'm pretty sure Ruby should return that array.

The error is saying "Hey I only see this result" but I'm expecting a string.